# Why is Resque incrementing a column count by 4-5 and not by 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

`Foobar.find(1).votes_count` returns 0.

In rails console, I am doing:

```
10.times { Resque.enqueue(AddCountToFoobar, 1) }
```

My resque worker:

```
class AddCountToFoobar
  @queue = :low

  def self.perform(id)
    foobar = Foobar.find(id)
    foobar.update_attributes(:count => foobar.votes_count +1)
  end
end
```

I would expect `Foobar.find(1).votes_count` to be `10`, but instead it returns 4. If I run `10.times { Resque.enqueue(AddCountToFoobar, 1) }` again, it returns the same behaviour. It only increments `votes_count` by 4 and sometimes 5.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic race condition scenario. Imagine that only 2 workers exist and that they each run one of your vote incrementing jobs. Imagine the following sequence.

1. Worker1: load foobar(vote count == 1)
2. Worker2: load foobar(vote count == 1, in a separate ruby object)
3. Worker 1: increment vote count (now == 2) and save
4. Worker 2: increment it's copy of foobar (vote count now == 2) and save, overwriting what worker 1 did

Although 2 workers ran 1 update job each, the count only increased by 1 because they were both operating on their own copy of foobar that wasn't aware of the change the other worker was doing

To solve this, you could either do an inplace style update, ie

```
UPDATE foos SET count = count + 1
```

or use one of the 2 forms of locking active record supports (pessimistic locking & optimistic locking)

The former works because the database ensures that you don't have concurrent updates on the same row at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Frederick. On your first suggestion. Just wondering why using raw sql would work? Could you explain a bit more about this approach

Comment: If you do update foos set blah = blah + 1 then the database acquires an exclusive lock for the duration of the statement

Comment: I see, and if there are any other similar statements executed at the same time. Then they will be queued on the db level? The statements wont be lost or not executed since the record is being locked?

Comment: Yes, the database takes care of that. One possibility with long lived locks (locks last as long as a transaction) is a deadlock (connection 1 has a lock on x and is waiting for one on y, connection 2 has a lock on y and is waiting for one of x) but that shouldn't happen here

Comment: Thanks this works! Just to take this a bit further. Will pessimistic locking in AR, render the same solution? Can't really see how transactions could work here

Comment: Pessimistic locking should work here. Optimistic locking is generally a little more work to get right but generally performs better if clashes are infrequent. I only mentioned transactions because once a (pessimistic) lock is acquired it lasts for the duration of the current transaction

Comment: So in essence, using AR's pessimistic locking feature is the same as using the raw sql approach? Or are there some differences?

Comment: But then again this using AR's pessimistic locking feature, won't solve this issue. Since we are trying to prevent AR in Resque from loading the same copy of the record. My understanding correct?

Comment: if you do `Foobar.lock(true).find(id)` from 2 different connections then the one of them will block until the other one has released the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ActiveRecord is not thread-safe in Resque (or rather redis, I guess). [Here's a nice explanation](http://www.rubyrobot.org/article/a-multithreaded-job-queue-for-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: If he uses multiple workers, it's no wonder. I'd use raw SQL UPDATE here.

Answer (score -1):

As Frederick says, you're observing a race condition.  You need to serialize access to the critical section from the time you read the value and update it.

I'd try to use pessimistic locking:
 http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html
 http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

```
foobar = Foobar.find(id)
foobar.with_lock do
  foobar.update_attributes(:count => foobar.votes_count +1)
end
```

Comment: The downvote wasn't from me, but your proposal won't solve the problem. You lock the table for the update but still fill it with data gathered from outside the critical section.